# combining macros in an excel worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm attempting to create a worksheet macro that will populate specific cells with default values in the same row when a value is entered in the first column of the row and also copy an entered value from the same row into other cells in that row.  For example, when the user enters some value in 2A, cells 2C and 2D automatically populate with the numbers 10 and 20 respectively.  Then, when the user enters a value in 2S, that same value is automatically copied back to cells 2I and 2J.

Thanks for the additional info Ralph. Based off of what I've found through researching similar questions on stackoverflow and general internet searches, I put together the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim A As Range, S As Range, InteA As Range, InteS As Range, r As Range
Set A = Range("A:A")
Set S = Range("S:S")
Set InteA = Intersect(A, Target)
Set InteS = Intersect(S, Target)
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Not InteA Is Nothing Then
    For Each r In InteA
        r.Offset(0, 2).Value = "10"
        r.Offset(0, 3).Value = "20"
    Next r
ElseIf Not InteS Is Nothing Then
    For Each r In InteS
        r.Offset(0, -9).Value = Target
        r.Offset(0, -10).Value = Target
        r.Offset(0, -11).Value = Target
    Next r
End If

Letscontinue:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
Whoa:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, DaddyLongLegs. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) with their code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Afterwards, update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve. Anyway, you might want to look into the `Worksheet_Change` events.

Comment: Just as a follow-up I am wondering: is there a question or did you post the answer to your own question as an edit to your original post (and deleted the original post)? It seems that the code is running without problems. Does it do what you want it to do?

Comment: I was having some issues with it yesterday where I wasn't getting any response when I entered values into columns A and S.  But I just tried it, and as you pointed out, it seems to be working fine now. Just had to change "S" to Target to get it to do exactly what I wanted.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get a macro to run, an event of some kind has to occur. Its tempting to try to run a macro whenever ANY change is made to the worksheet, but imagine how often that's going to trigger?  All the time.  Then you have to worry if 10 & 20 will start flying into those cells when you don't want them to and write some conditional code to skip the process if you aren't typing in column A...

So here's a different option you might prefer.  Enter formulas in columns C and D that will result in 10 & 20 if data exists in A.

> =IF(A2<>"",10,"")  or =IF(ISNUMBER(A2),10,0)  ...whatever you like.

Then select your header row and data row, convert to an real "Excel table" on the Insert menu. (Insert...Table) This will extend your formulas to new rows as you type into column A.

Macro averted?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not guaranteed to work. If someone else overwrites these "default" formulas with another formula (for example because he/she wants to fill that column with the value from column A plus column B) then you will very likely get different results / formulas for the next few inserted rows.

Comment: Thanks for the response Dory.  The reason I need to use a macro is because the number of rows that a user can enter values into may change depending on what the spreadsheet is being used for.  Essentially, I'm trying to make these entries dynamically based on the number of entries that are needed for the task.